# js - knockout Unable to process binding "text: function (){return

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

can't find where i made a mistake.
I get this error message when I run my code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return quoteAuthor }"
Message: quoteAuthor is not defined
```

newQuote might add new position to quotesArray, and cause adding new line tot able. It worked fine when newQuote had no ajax request, so added all times same object. ajax himself works too. Don't know what to do.
My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Your quotes</h2>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Автор</th>
                    <th>Цитата</th>
                    <th>Ссылка</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: quotesArray">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: quoteAuthor">toDo</td>
                    <td data-bind="text: quoteText">toDo</td>
                    <td data-bind="text: quoteLink">toDo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button data-bind="click: addQuote">Add quote</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="koQuotesScript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
function newQuote () {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax(
        {
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp : "jsonp",
        url : "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en",
        error : function(data) {
                alert("Error - 2");
        },
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
            self.quoteAuthor = response.quoteAuthor;
            self.quoteLink = response.quoteLink;
            self.quoteText = response.quoteText;
            console.log(self);
        }
    });
}   

function ModelView () {
    var self = this;

    self.quotesArray = ko.observableArray([
        {quoteAuthor: "Neil Alden Armstrong", 
        quoteLink: "https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong", 
        quoteText: "That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind."},

        {quoteAuthor: "Mark Twain (Samuel Langhorne Clemens)", 
        quoteLink: "https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mark_Twain", 
        quoteText: "If you tell the truth you don't have to remember anything."}
    ]);

    self.addQuote = function () {
        self.quotesArray.push(new newQuote());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ModelView());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a timing problem because your ajax call is asynchronous. When you first call `newQuote()` a new object is added immediately to the array, but that object lacks a quoteAuthor property. It lacks any properties at all until your ajax call returns at which time those properties are then defined, but in the meantime knockout has no idea what to bind to.

You can either give the quote object default values for those three properties, or you can restructure your code so that the object is not added to the array until the ajax call returns.